# How to calculate CPI from raw product sales data

Tags: econometrics

Consider the following predicate associated with the sales of consumer goods and services:

```
sale(T,P,C,U) :- C units of product P were sold at unit price U at time T
```

If we suppose we have recorded the extension of this predicate in some region, is there some basis for automatically calculating a CPI?